# How to change the last breadcrumb item name in wordpress using Breadcrumb navXT?

Tags: php, wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb of "Home | List New | Detail Post New", in which the "Detail Post New" page is fixed and I only pass the posts there, how can I change "Detail Post New" with the name of the example article:" Home | List New | Title Post 1 "

```
Home | List New | Detail Post New
```

change with each article

```
Home | List New | Title Post 1
```

my code

```
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="wrap-breadcrumb">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="https://schema.org/">
                <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
                {
                    bcn_display();
                }?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it with this 'crutch'.

1. I created new custom field with 'PODS' plugin. I added new breadcrumps title in this field.
2. I used 'bcn_breadcrumb_title' hook and got post 'ID'.
3. If my post 'ID' match with breadcrumps 'ID' then title is change.

(I'm sorry for my English)

```
add_filter('bcn_breadcrumb_title', 'my_breadcrumb_title_swapper', 3, 10);

function my_breadcrumb_title_swapper($title, $type, $id)
{

  $post = get_post();
  $post_id = $post->ID;

  if ( $post_id == $id )
  {
    if ( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_breadcrump_title', true) )
    {
      $title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_breadcrump_title', true);
    }
  }

  return $title;
  return $type;
  return $id;
}
```